# Unable to use gmail SMTP

Tags: node.js, smtp, gmail

I am trying to use gmail smtp using [`node_mailer`](https://github.com/Marak/node_mailer). I get following error on my nodejs logs (using [nodester](http://nodester.com)). Here is my code:

```
var email = require('mailer');
email.send({
    host : "smtp.gmail.com",              
    port : "465",                     
    ssl : true,
    domain : "domain.com",            
    to : "emailId@gmail.com",
    from : "email@gmail.com",
    subject : "You have been registered",
    body: "<B>Hello! This is a test of the node_mailer.</B>",
    authentication : "login",        // auth login is supported; anything else is no auth
    username : /* username */,
    password : /* password */      
    },
    function(err, result){
      if(err){ self.now.error(err); console.log(err); return;}
      else this.now.successfullySent(result);
});
```

I am not getting any error in the stack but email is not getting delivered.

@work4liberty and @David Ellis. Thanks for both of yours inputs but it seems that the problem was not with my server code, I was sending incorrect value in emailId from my client-side javascript. `Nodemailer` did help me debug the issue with correct text in error.

Comment: Please indent your code properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple things:

1. Your code as written will throw an interpreter error and not run. (No quotes around an email address, for instance.)
2. That library hasn't been updated in a while. I highly recommend the actively-developed and similarly-named [Nodemailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer) library that has shorthand for common services such as gmail's SMTP.

*Full Disclosure:* I contributed the Amazon SES functionality to Nodemailer (though a recent rewrite of the underlying architecture from 0.1.x to 0.3.x means I don't show up on `git blame`, anymore).

EDIT: I took a closer look at your code. Assuming you don't have the typos in your actual code, I suspect the following line is the culprit: `this.now.successfullySent(result);`

Basically, the callback function's `this` is *not* what you think it is. You'll want to cache the `this` object in its scope by assigning it to a variable like `self`. (Assuming we're not dealing with a problem in the underlying library.)

Comment: I accidentally removed quotes from around email address while posting here, I have corrected it. Also I have cached `this` into `self`. But that isn't the problem. Still I am unable to send mail. Good point though that this library hasn't been updated since last 7 months. Will try nodemailer.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the xxx with my password this code works for me
copy and paste that and see how it works
if it dose not work for you maybe it is just lag witch happens from time to time or (I hope not) your ip or something in your msg make gmail think it was spam

```
var email = require('mailer');
email.send({
    host : "smtp.gmail.com",
    port : "465",
    ssl : true,
    domain : "domain.com",
    to : "work4liberty@gmail.com",
    from : "work4liberty@gmail.com",
    subject : "You have been registered",
    body: "<B>Hello! This is a test of the node_mailer.</B>",
    authentication : "login",        // auth login is supported; anything else $
    username : 'work4liberty@gmail.com',
    password : 'xxx'
    },
    function(err, result){
      if(err){ self.now.error(err); console.log(err); return;}
      else console.log('looks good')
});
```

Comment: My code is exactly similar to yours. Still I am unable to send mail. It might be due to the fact that my app is deployed on nodester, any thoughts on that?

Comment: heh. You could try Nodemailer as suggestedas that is what i normally use. If you can find the ip you can check that agest spam databases or maybe even ask gmail directly if they are blocking it in some way. Maybe you could ask nodester if they are blocked by gmail or if they are blocking in some way.

Comment: Actually I tried both and now both are working. The problem was with my client side script. I was not fetching the email id correctly, Duh! How stupid of me. I've written this in my question.